# Uso mysql com laravel e os registros da tabela items estão sumindo o que pode ser?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

tenho uma base de dados mysql 5.7.29 chamada "base_default" com a collation e encoding de acordo com a imagem abaixo e a api usa Laravel 5.6.

[image: Configurações do encoding e collation]

nessa base possuo a seguinte estrutura de tabela ficha[id, protocolo], sub_ficha[id, ficha_id, aprovada[bool 0 ou 1]], items[id, nome, descricao, aprovado], todas elas possuem softdelete trait, então possuem created_at, updated_at e deleted_at

a questão é que começou a aparecer erros no sentry onde dizia não estar encontrando o id dos items, fui investigar e realmente o id procurado não estava mais no banco de dados.

ai fiz uma investigação no codigo que pesquisava esses items para ver se encontrava algo e nada, como não estava encontrando nada que deletasse ou alterasse o item pensei que poderia ser que o front estivesse pegando o id errado, então investiguei essa parte e fiz os testes com um novo item no qual eu realmente sabia o id ja que estava observando o banco e vi que estava pegando o item corretamente

ai eu fiz o seguinte, para sumir um item do banco mysql via codigo no Laravel precisa fazer um delete, destroy ou algum tipo de detach de acordo com a documentação https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships ou https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent, pesquisei por todos os metodos e o unico que encontrei foi o delete pelo model, o qual fiz testes e como o model possui softdelete apenas é preenchido a coluna deleted_at

não encontrei o problema no codigo, ai fiz o seguinte, agora to brabo então vo rebentar esse servidor, coloquei um log para qualquer query que o sistema faça no sistema no AppServiceProvider.php dentro do metodo boot()

```
         DB::listen(function ($query) {
            $bindings = '';
            foreach ($query->bindings as $key => $bind) {
                if ($bind instanceof \DateTime)
                    $bindings .= date_format($bind, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
                else if (is_bool($bind))
                    $bindings .= $bind ? '1' : '0';
                else
                    $bindings .= $bind;

                if ($key < count($query->bindings) - 1)
                    $bindings .= ', ';
            }
            File::append(
                storage_path('/logs/query.log'),
                 '[' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] => ' . $query->sql . ' [' . $bindings . '];' . PHP_EOL
            );
        });
```

depois de colocar o log fui no banco e coloquei 2 trigger uma que previne o item de ser deletado e uma que previne que o id do item seja alterado

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS items_prevent_delete;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER items_prevent_delete BEFORE DELETE ON items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.id > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Nenhum item pode ser deletado';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS items_prevent_update_id;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER items_prevent_update_id BEFORE UPDATE ON items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.id <> new.id THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Não pode alterar o id do item';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;

depois disso esperei fiz varios testes, otimizei codigos, revisei, fiz novas migrations, atualizei o layout do front e ai fui conferir os items, e adivinha os benditos sumiram mesmo com as 2 trigger rodando, então pensei, bom deve ter alguma pista no sentry ou no log das querys.

bom não havia nada no sentry a não ser o mesmo erro que dizia não estar encontrando os items e nas querys não havia nenhum comando de deleção ou atualização do item, o maximo que tinha era o select procurando o item que sumiu

Agora as perguntas, alguem mais ja passou por isso? será que a minha tabela esta muito grande pois possui 1 milhão de items? existe alguma outra forma de apagar um registro no banco de dados que não seja os que mencionei? preciso de alguma pista para poder encontrar o problema pois eu não faço mais idéia do porque os items da tabela items estão sumindo de forma aleatória.